# Google Colab No Such File or Directory Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Hello I'm trying to start tensorflow training process on google colab. I'm trying to run this code block in integrated notebook on google colab. Code block is:

```
!apt-get install protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml python-tk
!pip install Cython
%cd '/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/'
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/:/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/slim'

!python setup.py build
!python setup.py install
```

It gives this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
protobuf-compiler is already the newest version (3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1).
python-lxml is already the newest version (4.2.1-1ubuntu0.4).
python-pil is already the newest version (5.1.0-1ubuntu0.6).
python-tk is already the newest version (2.7.17-1~18.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (0.29.23)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research
python3: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python3: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I think I cant set python path correctly. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first mount your Google drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Try to do

```
import os
os.listdir(os.getcwd())
```

This should return

```
['.config', 'sample_data']
```

before you mount the drive, and

```
['.config', 'gdrive', 'sample_data']
```

after you've mounted the drive.